# How to query any field using wildcard in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently have a problem. I want to search exactly for field a and match the search for field b.

this is my code

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "multi_match": { "query": "biden","fields": [ "*.keyword"] } },
        { "wildcard": { "email.keyword": "123456*" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I not only want to use wildcard to search the 'email' field but also phone, name and any fields (maybe wildcard cannot do this) How can I do this?

Now, I'm not sure if wildcard will achieve what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use term query to return the exact string provided on that field, if that’s the case.

For example, we have multiple docs in index hello_world. But searching for word “Blippi and the whole gang” reveals more exact results than we are looking for:

```
GET  /hello_world/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "doc.play_name.keyword": {
                    "value": "Blippi and the whole gang",
                    "boost": 1.0
                    }
              }},{
                "term": {
                    "doc.protagonist.keyword": {
                    "value": "Blippi and the whole gang",
                    "boost": 1.0
                }
            }}]
        }
    }
}
```

Result shows:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.0726933,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "hello_world",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 3.0726933,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "type": "diretory",
            "play_name": "Blippi and the whole gang",
            "movie_time_minutes": 0,
            "characters": 2,
            "protagonist": "Blippi and the whole gang",
            "director": "Blippi and the whole gang"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For exact matching, you need to use `must` with `term` query as:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "field" : "value" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For wildcard searches, `wildcard` query can be used. As later mentioned in the question that the wildcard is needed for multiple fields like email, phone, name or any other field, it would be as follows if the field values to be matched are different:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "field": "value"
                }
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "field1": "*"+"input"+"*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "field2": "*"+"input"+"*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For multiple field matching same search text, the multi-match query can be used. The multi-match query is built on top of match queries, according to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html):

> The multi_match query builds on the match query to allow multi-field
> queries

Wildcards can be specified but only for fields, according to the  [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#field-boost):

> Fields can be specified with wildcards

Hope this helps.